# How to change list position in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#Finds the Image descriptions and saves to a list
url = 'http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/lg_image_of_the_day.rss'
describe_text = urlopen(url).read()
description = findall('<description>(.+)</description>',describe_text)
x = description[1]

#Button Functions
def next_button_description():
       Help
```

Each time i press my widget Button it will call the function and i need description[1] to change position to description[2] and so on... each time the button is pressed. i am clearly a novice with python please help!! using python 2.7

Comment: when you change description[1] to description[2], what do you want top add in description[1]

Comment: basically description is a list of descriptions when the program runs it pulls the first description from the list. When i press my widget button i need it to change the description to the next in the list.

Comment: I would suggest you declare a variable as 0 (i.e myVar = 0), when pulling the description, instead of calling descption[1], call x = description[myVar], then each time you run your button function, increment myVar like i.e (myVar = myVar + 1)

Comment: If you can loose the first description then just `x = description.pop(0)`.  Remember that python lists start their index positions from zero, not one (like most programming languages, but not all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the first part of your code is the "main" that runs on startup of the script, this is probably not the best place to pull the information from the list, as if you plan on pulling it more than once, you will have to rerun this code over and over, which will include requesting the list contents from the URL over and over as well, what would be easier is to pull the list from the URL once, and then use your widget function to access the list like so:

```
url = 'http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/lg_image_of_the_day.rss'
describe_text = urlopen(url).read()
description = findall('<description>(.+)</description>',describe_text)
global myVariable
myVariable = 1
x = description[myVariable]


#Button Functions
def next_button_description():
   global myVariable
   myVariable = myVariable + 1
   x = description[myVariable]
   return x
```

The variable "myVariable" will increment each time you run the function, starting from 1 the first time you run it, and then 2 and 3 and so on.

The next_button_description() function will return the next index each time it is run.

Hope this helps.

Comment: description[0] is rubbish that i dont need to show so when the program is run it needs to start at [1]. is there someway to private chat on stackoverflow? I would like to show you my whole program

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but hang on. Let me edit my answer and I think it will work for you

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myVariable' referenced before assignment i recieve that error

Comment: Sorry, you will need to pass the variable into the function, let me edit

Comment: button_next = Button(photo_browser, text = '   Next>  ', command = next_button_description(argument)) # so what do i make the argument

Comment: mike19891@outlook.com can you email me your contact details. i would like to send you my script

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
    description.insert(0, <new description>)
```

it will add new description to the front and shift all the others

Comment: I don't think hes trying to add to his list, but pull the next value from his list

Comment: He wrote he wants to change the positions

Comment: Yeah he did, but I think what he means is he wants to access the value, stored in the next position